# What is the difference betweend LTDL_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, autotools

In compiling and linking `C` and `C++` code, what is the purpose of `LTDL_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables? In addition what is the difference between them?

Thanks

Comment: These tags have nothing to do with your question. I think only *glibc* cares about `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` a [tag:c] or [tag:c++] program would only care if it explicitly does.

Comment: @iharob Actually I believe C and C++ programs do use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when looking for shared libraries, including the C++ standard library on Linux.

Comment: Not c and c++ the runtime does.

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for the dynamic linker to search for libraries to load. Never heard of `LTDL_LIBRARY_PATH`. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LTDL_LIBRARY_PATH` sets a library search path for the [libtool library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Introduction.html#Introduction), a helper/portability library for using shared libraries.  That library will search the directories in this path before searching `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which is an environment variable that sets a search path for the system's shared library loader.

From the [libtool documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Libltdl-interface.html#Libltdl-interface):

> If `libltdl` cannot find the library and the file name filename does not
>   have a directory component it will additionally look in the following
>   search paths for the module (in the following order):
>
> - user-defined search path: This search path can be changed by the program using the functions `lt_dlsetsearchpath`, `lt_dladdsearchdir` and
>     `lt_dlinsertsearchdir`.
> - `libltdl`’s search path: This search path is the value of the environment variable `LTDL_LIBRARY_PATH`.
> - system library search path: The system dependent library search path (e.g. on GNU/Linux it is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`)

As mentioned above, [`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is an environment variable that the system will use](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html#AEN80) to search for shared libraries.